# Effect of static and dynamic linking on start address

Tags: c, gcc, dynamic-linking, static-linking

I have a simple C program. I run:

```
$ gcc Q1.c -Wall -save-temps -o Q1
```

Then I inspect the executable generated:

```
$  objdump -f Q1
Q1:     file format elf32-i386
architecture: i386, flags 0x00000112:
EXEC_P, HAS_SYMS, D_PAGED
start address 0x080483b0
```

Then I compile it with static linking:

```
$ gcc Q1.c -Wall -save-temps -static -o Q1
```

and inspect the file again:

```
$ objdump -f Q1
Q1:     file format elf32-i386
architecture: i386, flags 0x00000112:
EXEC_P, HAS_SYMS, D_PAGED
start address 0x08048e08
```

What effect does static and dynamic linking have on the start address of the program? The start address is the address of `main()`, right?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### The start address is the address of `main()`, right?

Not really: The start of a program isn't really `main()`. By default, GCC will produce executables whose start address corresponds to the `_start` symbol. You can see that by doing a `objdump --disassemble Q1`. Here's the output on a simple program of mine that only does `return 0;` in `main()`:

```
0000000000400e30 <_start>:
  400e30:       31 ed                   xor    %ebp,%ebp
  400e32:       49 89 d1                mov    %rdx,%r9
  400e35:       5e                      pop    %rsi
  400e36:       48 89 e2                mov    %rsp,%rdx
  400e39:       48 83 e4 f0             and    $0xfffffffffffffff0,%rsp
  400e3d:       50                      push   %rax
  400e3e:       54                      push   %rsp
  400e3f:       49 c7 c0 a0 15 40 00    mov    $0x4015a0,%r8
  400e46:       48 c7 c1 10 15 40 00    mov    $0x401510,%rcx
  400e4d:       48 c7 c7 40 0f 40 00    mov    $0x400f40,%rdi
  400e54:       e8 f7 00 00 00          callq  400f50 <__libc_start_main>
  400e59:       f4                      hlt    
  400e5a:       66 90                   xchg   %ax,%ax
  400e5c:       0f 1f 40 00             nopl   0x0(%rax)
```

As you can see at address `400e54`, `_start()` in turn invokes `__libc_start_main`, which initializes the necessary stuff (pthreads, atexit,...) and finally calls `main()` with the appropriate arguments (argc, argv and env).

#### Okay, but what does it have to do with the start address changing?

When you ask `gcc` to link statically, it means that all the initialization that I mentioned above has to be done using functions that are in the executable. And indeed if you look at the sizes of both executables, you'll find that the static version is way larger. On my test, the static version is 800K while the shared version is only 6K.

The extra functions happen to be placed before `_start()`, hence the change in start address. Here's the layout of the static executable around `start()`:

```
000000000049e960 r translit_from_tbl
0000000000400a76 t _i18n_number_rewrite
0000000000400bc0 t fini
0000000000400bd0 t init_cacheinfo
0000000000400e30 T _start
0000000000400e60 t deregister_tm_clones
0000000000400e90 t register_tm_clones
0000000000400ed0 t __do_global_dtors_aux
```

And here's the layout of the shared executable:

```
00000000004003c0 T _start
00000000004003f0 t deregister_tm_clones
00000000004004b0 T main
00000000004004c0 T __libc_csu_init
00000000006008a0 B _end
0000000000400370 T _init
```

As a result, I get slightly different start addresses: 0x400e30 in the static case and 0x4003c0 in the shared case.